# Do golfers not wear funny hats?

Tags: discussion

How come we're not part of the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/)? Do golfers not wear funny hats?

Comment: Golfers wear funny pants. And socks. And especially cardigans.

Comment: Polka-dot bow-ties? (I can't seem to picture anything but Larry Moe and the third guy)

Comment: Maybe they should have the winter bash in winter. Oh there's another hemisphere? Ah right, I keep forgetting about all those folks.

Comment: What's wrong with not wearing hats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we were planning out the master list of In/Out, I did my best to cycle through all sites' metas and mod chatrooms to see if there was any chatter about HATS and if I could help out.

Unfortunately, I didn't see any chatter -- meta posts, chatroom, etc -- here about hats, and when the deadline passed I was obligated to opt Code Golf Stack Exchange out of the running. :(

Not to worry. There's always next year! :D

Comment: Understood. thanks.

Comment: Why would there have been chatter about hats? I didn't see any mention of them until I got my first notification saying that I'd qualified for one.

Comment: @Aarthi When should we start chattering next year?

Comment: @luserdroog Probably in late October or November. :)